# How do I make F1 be a hotkey in Windows XP assigned to creating a new folder?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, autohotkey

How do I make <kbd>F1</kbd> be a hotkey in Windows XP assigned to creating a new folder?

I don't know too much about programming or scripting. Can AutoHotkey do this?

Comment: Where is the new folder to be located?

Comment: Hi Martin, I think the new folder should be created in the same folder/desktop that I am browsering.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yup. Use [FileCreateDir](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/FileCreateDir.htm).

```
windowText =
line =
path =
name =

$F1::                                                   ;the $ locks the keystroke so you don't get Windows Help
    IfWinNotActive, ahk_class CabinetWClass
        Return                                          ;If the active window is not an explorer window, do nothing
    WinGetText, windowText, ahk_class CabinetWClass,    ;get text info
    StringSplit, line, windowText, `n                   ;take the first line of windowText this will be "Address: path"
    StringReplace, path, line1, Address: `              ;trim off Address: 
    StringTrimRight, path, path, 1                      ;trim off new line character at the end
    InputBox, name, MakeDirF1, Enter the name of the new folder.    ;get a name
    If name == ""                                       ;if name is blank
        name := "New Folder"                            ;then set name
    FileCreateDir, %path%\%name%                        ;create the folder
    If ErrorLevel == 1                                  ;check for errors
        MsgBox, Error!`n`n%A_LastError%                 ;message box if error
    Return
```

Comment: Thanks, Ampersand, it really works! Though there seem to be a little problem creating new folder just on the Desktop

Comment: Hmm... sorry for the late reply.

It would work if you navigated to the desktop in an Explorer window.

Otherwise, you can just map a key to send the requisite keystrokes.
$F1::
{
Click, Right
Send, wf
RETURN
}

Comment: @Ampersand: Seems like you could detect when the desktop is active by looking for an active window of `ahk_class Progman` and then automatically create a subfolder in the user's desktop folder if that's the case.  Also, at least on my XP SP3 system, Explorer windows have a `ahk_class ExploreWClass`, not `CabinetWClass`.